# how to bundle com.sun.tools.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin, Where i need to use the tools.jar as an dependency.As we know eclipse does not take normal jar as dependencies. so i tried to change the jar as osgi bundle. But the generated osgi bundle does not contain the com.sun packages inside.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I tried to bundle all the dependencies given in the pom.

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nuwaza.aqua</groupId>
<artifactId>osgi-tool-bundle</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>osgi-tool-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>                     
                    <Bundle-Name>osgi-tool-bundle</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>com.nuwaza.aqua.bundle</Private-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.nuwaza.aqua.bundle.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime|system</Embed-Dependency>                 
                    <Embed-Directory>target/dependency</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-StripGroup>true</Embed-StripGroup>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>
          </plugin>
        <profiles>
        <profile>
          <activation>
              <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <osgi-version-qualifier>qualifier</osgi-version-qualifier>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- PDE does not honour custom manifest location -->
                            <manifestLocation>META-INF</manifestLocation>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The generated bundle only contains `org.osgi` packages not `com.sun` packages. I even included system scope in `<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime|system</Embed-Dependency>`.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Why do you need to bundle `com.sun.tools`? It should already be available in the JDK that people will already have installed when they would use your plug-in.

Comment: @Jesper I have tried without packing the tools.jar . But during the runtime i am getting error like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/VMDisconnectedException ` I guess its because my plugin is not able to get the required class files at runtime.

Comment: then how to access the com.sun.tools from my plugin without bundling it ?

Comment: you need to make a fat jar. It includes all your dependencies. so then you just need tools.jar and nothing else. I know how to do it for gradle. But you are working on maven.